# How do I implement mention of users after @ (AT) as in Twitter or WhatsApp?

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate, mention

Help me please implement UITextView, which will be able to recognise @.
When I'm typing characters of the username required after @, there is filtered tableView with the username appearing, in which I click on çell and username is inserted in the text.

Answer (score 1):

No sure if you figured this out yet or not, but I created a simple class to do this.

You can find it here: https://github.com/omar14/OEMentions

OEMentions.swift is the file where all the logic is implemented, I think it will be useful for you.

Comment: Any such solution for Android?